# Importing CSS with @import in conjunction with @charset

Tags: css, utf-8, import, character-encoding

If I use the following at the top of my CSS file **home.css**:

```
@import "overall.css";
```

Do I need to (within **home.css**) redeclare `@charset "utf-8";` or is this applied to the current CSS document when it's been defined within the included CSS?

Comment: You should define it at the top of the first CSS file, the it will apply to all that are included using @import.

Comment: Thanks, if you post that as an answer I'll be able to accept it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define it at the top of the first CSS file, the it will apply to all that are included using @import.

Comment: I had a problem with a non-ASCII character in a SCSS file in a Ruby Sinatra application, and in fact i had to do the opposite to what you suggest to make it work: i had to add `@charset` at the top of the included file that contained the non-ASCII character.  Adding it at the top of the main file did not help and was not necessary.

Comment: That's strange, why not remove the non ASCII character?

Comment: I think all characters should be acceptable in comments.  Anyway, i solved the issue with `@charset`.

Comment: Can I get a citation for this behavior? I would like to learn more.